# How to import "orange" in ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, orange

I am a Windows 8.1 user, and I downloaded anaconda package to install python environment.  (http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/)

when I import orange on ipython notebook, it shows " ImportError: No module named Orange"

I just downloaded the file "Orange-2.7.8.tar.gz" on orange's website. Is it what I need now? how can I install orange package in my anaconda environment?

I check this question "http://orange.biolab.si/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1870" and found the website to download the .whl file, but I still dont know how to install the package in win8.

Comment: That package is on pyPI.  did you try `conda install Orange` or `pip install Orange`?

Comment: thank you so much!   I just tried pip install Orange and it works!